# Imperative access to database

Tags: database, imperative

I'm interested if anyone knows of a database server, which offers imperative access to the data (skipping query parsing, estimation) and providing the client something like "file" api access to the data?
Thanks

Comment: Very confused, never saw the words imperative and database being used in one sentence.  Do you mean something like ISAM?

Comment: @fvu - I think so, thanks, that's the kind of interface I was asking for.

Comment: Having worked with a database system that didn’t use a declarative query language but required imperative calls (e.g. to loop through an index, or to update a data set), I can tell you that you definitely don’t want to do that. Query processors in modern database engines are incredibly smart and can optimize more than you can probably think about, so just trust them to do fulfill your declarative query well. However, you might be interested in [document databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database) instead.